# Unity lerp doesn't lerp, it just moves immediately

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I cannot for life of me figure this one out. This exact code works correctly for my `Camera.Main` object. My door needs to `Lerp` up when activated by an external switch, but for some reason no matter what value I put in there it immediately jumps up, it doesn't slowly move up like I would prefer. This code is placed in my `void Update()` block, any ideas? What am I doing wrong, am I misunderstanding the use of `Lerp`?

```
private Transform objTransform = null;
public bool isDoorOpen = false;
private Vector3 posDoorStart;
public Vector3 posDoorEnd;
public float DoorSmoothing = 2.0f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    objTransform = transform;
    posDoorStart = transform.position;
}

void Update() {
    if (isDoorOpen)
    {
        float smoothing = DoorSmoothing;
        // Also tried this...
        // float smoothing = DoorSmoothing * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(posDoorStart, posDoorEnd, smoothing);
    }
}
```

Transform starting values:
[image]

Gate script values:
[image]

Also, on occasion if I set the lerp too low, as in this example, it only partially moves to the location I want. It has to hit around `1.5` before it'll go all the way up, otherwise I get something like this...

[image]

Comment: posDoorEnd is set in editor correctly?

Comment: @Reniuz It is. I posted the values.

Comment: Also your smoothing variable is always same. It should be between 0 and 1. [Look at example](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) and try to calculate smoothing like there.

Comment: Try to set smoothing to 0.5 - and after lerp your door should be opened in half way

Comment: @Reniuz It does open halfway, but it still opens immediately with `Lerp`. Want it to move over a second or so.

Comment: Yes because your value is fixed. You need to calculate the percentage of opened door on every update. See the link to example I posted in prev comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the door working peeeeeerfectly! Extremely smooth and no the `isDoorOpen` variable can be private. Just generated a public method to kick off the door opening. Tried to put the `Time.time` setting in the `Start` method, figured out that made a silly jump for the first movement, set it at the time of activation and fixed all the issues. Door is fixed.

```
private Transform objTransform = null;
private float startTime;
private float DistanctToTravel = 0.0f;
private bool isDoorOpen = false;
private Vector3 posDoorStart;

public Vector3 posDoorEnd;
public float DoorSmoothing = 1.0f;

void Start () {
    objTransform = transform;
    posDoorStart = transform.position;
}

void Update() {
    if (objTransform != null)
    {
        if (isDoorOpen)
        {
            float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * DoorSmoothing;
            float smoothing = distCovered / DistanctToTravel;
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(posDoorStart, posDoorEnd, smoothing);
        }
    }
}

public void OpenDoor(){
    startTime = Time.time;
    isDoorOpen = true;
    DistanctToTravel = Vector3.Distance (posDoorEnd, posDoorStart);
}
```

Comment: As an extension of this you might want to lookup "coroutines" in the unity docs/learn resources. This is the kind of thing that works well with "do something over time based on a one off trigger event" :)

Comment: @Lefty You mean something to the effect of `StartCoroutine("DoorOperation");` and place the block found inside of `if (isDoorOpen)` in a new `private void DoorOperation ()`?